# tikz: number precision when incrementing by 0.01

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I increment the y axis by 0.01, the numbers encounter a rounding error for some weird reason.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y in {0.01, 0.02, ... 0.1}{
    \draw (0, \y cm) -- (-0.1cm, \y) node[left] {$\y$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a known issue. Use `\pgfmathprintnumber` or `\num` from the `siunitx` package to fix how the numbers are displayed.